# Merging types from variadic template using template-template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-templates

I'm trying to extend a list of arguments being passed via a template template. The first example works, the second doesn't. The result I'm looking for would be that in the second example, `cWapperObject.cMemberVariable.cTuple` is of type `std::tuple<double, float, short, int>`. How can I achieve this? (And please, please do not mention the library boost in the comments or answers).

**Example 1:**

```
#include <tuple>

template<class ... TS> class CObject {
   std::tuple<TS ...> cTuple;
};

template<template<typename ... TS> class TMPL_CLASS_T>
class CWrapperObject {
    TMPL_CLASS_T<double, float, short> cMemberVariable;
};

int main() {
   CWrapperObject<CObject> cWapperObject;
   return 0;
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
#include <tuple>

template<class ... TS> class CObject {
   std::tuple<TS ...> cTuple;
};

template<template<typename ... TS> class TMPL_CLASS_T>
class CWrapperObject {
    TMPL_CLASS_T<double, float, TS ...> cMemberVariable;
};

int main() {
   CWrapperObject<CObject<short, int>> cWapperObject;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using gcc version 4.9.2, the reported error is main.cc:9:33: error: ‘TS’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CObject` is a class template, it can be used as a template-template argument. `CObject<short, int>` is a type, it can't be used as a template-template argument, neither a template-template parameter itself carries any actual type template arguments. You can still deduce the class template name and its parameters using a partial specialization, utilizing a template-template parameter, along with actual type template arguments that were used to instantiate the template:

```
template <typename... TS>
struct CObject
{
    std::tuple<TS...> cTuple;
};

template <typename>
struct CWrapperObject;

template <template <typename...> class TMPL_CLASS_T, typename... TS>
struct CWrapperObject<TMPL_CLASS_T<TS...>>
{
    TMPL_CLASS_T<double, float, TS...> cMemberVariable;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da413da529045fd3)

Comment: Excellent answer and thanks for the demo! If you would like another challenge, have a go and see if you can propose a solution to this one: [Tagging objects using enums via template-template parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305628/tagging-objects-using-enums-via-template-template-parameters)