# Tagging objects using enums via template-template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums, template-templates

I would like to use an enum argument of a template, to restrict a second argument, a class, to in turn taking an member of the enum as an argument as it's templated parameter. In code, I would expect this to look like:

```
CObject<EObjectTag, CSubObject<EObjectTag::CAT_A>> cObject;
```

this should work, however:

```
CObject<EObjectTag, CSubObject<ENotAnObjectTag::CAT_OTHER>> cObject;
```

should fail as `ENotAnObjectTag::CAT_OTHER` is not a element of `EObjectTag`.

My implementation (attempt) of this, is as follows and bombs out during compilation (on gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)) with the error message:

> source.cc:16:45: error: ‘SUBOBJECT_TAG’ was not declared in this scope
>   struct CObject>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

enum class EObjectTag {CAT_A, CAT_B, CAT_OTHER};

// CSubObject
template<class OBJECT_TAG_T, OBJECT_TAG_T OBJECT_TAG>
struct CSubObject { OBJECT_TAG_T m_tTag = OBJECT_TAG; };

// CObject - Forward declaration
template <class SUBOBJECT_TAG_T, template <SUBOBJECT_TAG_T SUBOBJECT_TAG> class SUBOBJECT_T>
struct CObject;

// CObject - Specialization
template <class SUBOBJECT_TAG_T, template <SUBOBJECT_TAG_T SUBOBJECT_TAG> class SUBOBJECT_T>
struct CObject<SUBOBJECT_T<SUBOBJECT_TAG_T, SUBOBJECT_TAG>>
{
   public:
      SUBOBJECT_T<SUBOBJECT_TAG_T, SUBOBJECT_TAG> m_cSubObject;
};

int main() {
   // The aim is that the second object only accepts a tag that 
   // belongs to EObjectTag
   CObject<EObjectTag, CSubObject<EObjectTag::CAT_A>> cObject;

   return 0;
}
```

The final use case for this involves replacing CSubObject with CObject so that we can use recursion to define a hierarchy of tagged objects, which also requires the use of variadic templates to have multiple objects at the same level. For example:

```
/* EBase, */
CObject</*EBase::BASE,*/ EObject,
    CObject<EObject::INIT, EInitObject,
        CObject<EInitObject::INIT_FOO>,
        CObject<EInitObject::INIT_BAR>,
    >,
    CObject<EObject::COUNT, ECountObject,
        CObject<ECountObject::COUNT_FOO>,
        CObject<ECountObject::COUNT_BAR>,
    >,
> cMyObjectHierarchy;
```

The commented out references to EBase (an enum internal to the library) are there to keep the template parameters of CObject consistent, I would plan (if possible) to do this automatically via template specialization or default arguments.

My goals of specifying this hierarchy of objects would in addition include:

1. Avoid forcing the user of this library to define additional classes
   or structs in their program
2. Leverage compile time checking via the
   templating of CObject with an enum, whose functions in turn use that
   enum as an argument to a set of functions common to all CObjects

Comment: Please describe a clear problem statement or question.  You have ambiguous goals (leverage compile time checking as much as possible, etc), but nothing *clear*.  I can (and have) described a myriad of problems with your code, but that doesn't get us close to fixing your actual problem, because your actual problem is unclear.  You seem to have a goal, and you have generated a bunch of code that doesn't solve it, but that doesn't communicate what your goal is.

Comment: @Yakk thank you for the feedback, I have updated the wording the first section of my question and removed the last section as it was really relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to make it compile. Although I'm not 100% sure if this actually does what you *want* it to do; I agree with most of what Yakk sais in his answer.

Note: the following will *not* compile because I deliberately tried to mix a type of one enum with a value of another enum to verify that it indeed triggers a compile-time error, which I think is sort of what you asked for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

enum class EObjectTag {CAT_A, CAT_B, CAT_OTHER};
enum class FObjectTag {DOG_A, DOG_B, DOG_OTHER};

// CSubObject
template<typename OBJECT_TAG_T, OBJECT_TAG_T OBJECT_TAG>
struct CSubObject { OBJECT_TAG_T m_tTag = OBJECT_TAG; };

// CObject - Specialization
template <class SUBOBJECT_TAG_T, SUBOBJECT_TAG_T SUBOBJECT_TAG, template <typename TYPE_T, TYPE_T TYPE> class SUBOBJECT_T>
struct CObject
{
   public:
      SUBOBJECT_T<SUBOBJECT_TAG_T, SUBOBJECT_TAG> m_cSubObject;
};

int main() {
   // The aim is that the second object only accepts a tag that 
   // belongs to EObjectTag
   CObject<EObjectTag, EObjectTag::CAT_A, CSubObject> cObject1;
   CObject<EObjectTag, FObjectTag::DOG_B, CSubObject> cObject2;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had something similar to this before, but unfortunately moving the enum value outside of the class template parameters isn't a plausible solution. This is because it prevents an unspecified number of arguments via a variadic templates, where alternating value and type parameters are not supported...

Comment: I have updated the question to improve clarity and also to refine my use case

Answer (score 2):

An argument of `template <SUBOBJECT_TAG_T SUBOBJECT_TAG> class SUBOBJECT_T` is a template, not an instance of a template.  `CSubObject<blah>` cannot match the kind `template<...>class`, because `CSubObject<blah>` is a *type* that is generated by the template, not a template.  `template<...>class` parameters are templates, not types.

In addition, `CSubObject` is of kind `template<class T, T> class`, not `template<SUBOBJECT_TAG_T>class`.  It takes two arguments, the first a type, the second a constant of that type: the kind `template<SUBOBJECT_TAG_T>class` is a template that takes one argument of type `SUBOJECT_TAG_T`.  These are unrelated kinds of template.

Second, you seem to have issues with template specializations.  Template specializations are pattern-matching of your primary specialization.  They are not "new overloads".  So arguments to `CObject` must first match the kinds of arguments the primary specialization of `CObject` expects.  The stuff within `template< blah >` are used to pattern match the pattern in the `CObject< blah >` part of the specialization.

In general, it is conventional to use ALL CAPS only for macros, not for template arguments.

These are all problems with your code in your question.  Your code lacks a clear problem statement or question, so the best I can do is describe fixes to your myriad of problems.

---

You have revised your question a bit.

```
template<class T, class U>
struct CObject;

template<class T, template<class Q, Q>class Z, T t>
struct CObject< T, Z<T, t> > {
};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ea3b0e21f5bc39c).

Now, you still have to pass `CSubObject<EObjectTag, EObjectTag::CAT_A>` as the 2nd parameter.

You could also add a specialization:

```
template<class T, template<T>class Z, T t>
struct CObject< T, Z<t> > {
};
```

which, if you had a `template<EObjectTag tag> struct Example;`, you could `CObject< EObjectTag, Example<EObjectTag::bob> >` as well.

Comment: I'm having a look at this approach to the problem. It is good, but having to define an struct using: `template<EObjectTag tag> struct Example;` defeats the purpose as it would require this definition for every type of enum that needs to be defined...

Comment: @allsey Your requirements remain vague.  The fact that defining such a struct was what you wanted to avoid was not mentioned.  I still have little idea why you have the 'subobject' type at all.

Comment: I have updated the question again and added the primary use case to the end. Sorry about so many revisions, but since this is a question regarding design, it is quite challenging to decouple the use case from my core question